# Why is ScollView content size not adjusting properly for this SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using Xcode beta7 and the following is the code.
This is for a MacOs app.

here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isClicked = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Click me").onTapGesture {
                self.isClicked.toggle()
            }.border(Color.red)
            V1(isClicked: $isClicked)
        }
    }
}

struct V1: View {
    @Binding var isClicked: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if isClicked {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("value \(index)")
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Run this code and click on the **Click me** button.
You will see that the scrollView's contnent size does not update and stay's squished.

If i try to resize the frame of the application by using the mouse to resize the screen, then instantly, the ScrollView's content size snaps to the correct size.

Do i need to do something to get the ScrollView to do this automatically (instead of me having to manually inscrease the frame of the app with the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently on iOS, watchOS. The only way, I solve it was to move the content of the scrollView as a func in your struct having the ScrollView. As shown below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isClicked = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Click me").onTapGesture {
                self.isClicked.toggle()
            }.border(Color.red)
            otherView()
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

    func otherView() -> some View{
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if isClicked {
                ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("value \(index)")
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

It looks like a bug.